# How to assign a unique ID number to each group of identical values in a column

Tags: r, dataframe, unique

I have a data frame with a number of columns. I would like to create a new column called “id” that gives a unique id number to each group of identical values in the “sample” column.

Example data:

```
df <- data.frame(
  index = 1:30,
  val = c(
    14L, 22L, 1L, 25L, 3L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 24L, 35L, 33L, 31L, 30L,
    30L, 29L, 28L, 26L, 12L, 41L, 36L, 32L, 37L, 56L, 34L, 23L, 24L,
    28L, 22L, 10L, 19L
  ),
  sample = c(
    5L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L,
    14L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 18L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 20L, 21L,
    22L, 23L, 23L
  )
)
```

What I would like to end up with:

```
  index val sample id
1     1  14      5  1
2     2  22      6  2
3     3   1      6  2
4     4  25      7  3
5     5   3      7  3
6     6  34      7  3
```

Comment: dplyr solution: `df$id <- group_indices(df$sample)`.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

How about

```
df2 <- transform(df,id=as.numeric(factor(sample)))
```

?

I think this (cribbed from [Add ID column by group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13566562/creating-an-unique-id-in-r)) should be slightly more efficient, although perhaps a little harder to remember:

```
df3 <- transform(df, id=match(sample, unique(sample)))
all.equal(df2,df3)  ## TRUE
```

If you want to do this in tidyverse:

```r
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(sample) %>% mutate(id=cur_group_id())
```

Comment: Love it: a use for `factors` that I can understand.  :-)

Comment: Just a small note here: the `as.numeric(factor(sample))` method will only result in a descending numbers sequence if `sample` is already ordered.

Comment: the nice thing about the `factor()` solution is that it ignores `NA` values

Comment: @Ben Bolker, thanks! can you write your code with `dplyr`?

Comment: did you see the comment above https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24119599/how-to-assign-a-unique-id-number-to-each-group-of-identical-values-in-a-column/24119941?noredirect=1#comment101022995_24119599 ?

Comment: @Ben Bolker, I assumed  I can write your code using `dplyr`

Answer (score 47):

Here's a `data.table` solution

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, id := .GRP, by = sample]
```