# Order factor levels in order of appearance in data set

Tags: r, data.table, r-factor

I have a survey in which a unique ID must be assigned to questions. Some questions appear multiple times. This means that there is an extra layer of questions. In the sample data below only the first layer is included.

Question: how do I assign a unique index by order of appearance? The solution provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24119599/how-to-assign-a-unique-id-number-to-each-group-of-identical-values-in-a-column/24119941#24119941) works alphabetically. I can order the factors, but this defeats the purpose of doing it in R [there are many questions to sort].

```
library(data.table)
dt = data.table(question = c("C", "C", "A", "B", "B", "D"), 
                value = c(10,20,30,40,20,30))

dt[, idx := as.numeric(as.factor(question))]
```

gives:

```
  question value idx
# 1:        C    10   3
# 2:        C    20   3
# 3:        A    30   1
# 4:        B    40   2
# 5:        B    20   2
# 6:        D    30   4

# but required is:
dt[, idx.required := c(1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4)]
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think the `data.table` way to do this will be

```
dt[, idx := .GRP, by = question]

##    question value idx
## 1:        C    10   1
## 2:        C    20   1
## 3:        A    30   2
## 4:        B    40   3
## 5:        B    20   3
## 6:        D    30   4
```

Comment: +1 for LukeA but this is indeed more compact. Both solutions work.

Comment: What is `idx := .GRP`?

Answer (score 8):

You could respecify the factor levels:

```
dt[, idx := as.numeric(factor(question, levels=unique(question)))]
#    question value idx
# 1:        C    10   1
# 2:        C    20   1
# 3:        A    30   2
# 4:        B    40   3
# 5:        B    20   3
# 6:        D    30   4
```