# Assign ID across 2 columns of variable

Tags: r, unique, recode

I have a data frame in which each individual (row) has two data points per variable.

Example data:

```
df1 <- read.table(text = "IID L1.1 L1.2 L2.1 L2.2 
                        1  1  38V1 38V1 48V1 52V1
                        2  2  36V1 38V2 50V1 48Y1
                        3  3  37Y1 36V1 50V2 48V1
                        4  4  38V2 36V2 52V1 50V2",
  stringsAsFactor = FALSE, header = TRUE)
```

I have many more columns than this in the full dataset and would like to recode these values to label unique identifiers across the two columns. I know how to get identifiers and relabel a single column from previous questions ([Creating a unique ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13566562/creating-a-unique-id) and [How to assign a unique ID number to each group of identical values in a column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24119599/how-to-assign-a-unique-id-number-to-each-group-of-identical-values-in-a-column)) but I don't know how to include the information for two columns, as R identifies and labels factors per column.

Ultimately I want something that would look like this for the above data:

```
(df2)
  IID L1.1 L1.2 L2.1 L2.2 
1  1   1    1    1    4
2  2   2    4    2    5
3  3   3    2    3    1
4  4   1    5    4    3
```

It doesn't really matter what the numbers are, as long as they indicate unique values across both columns. I've tried creating a function based on the output from:

```
unique(df1[,1:2])
```

but am struggling as this still looks at unique entries per column, not across the two.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this would work...

```
pairs <- (ncol(df1)-1)/2
for(i in 1:pairs){
  refs <- unique(c(df1[,2*i],df1[,2*i+1]))
  df1[,2*i] <- match(df1[,2*i],refs)
  df1[,2*i+1] <- match(df1[,2*i+1],refs)
}

df1
  IID L1.1 L1.2 L2.1 L2.2
1   1    1    1    1    4
2   2    2    4    2    5
3   3    3    2    3    1
4   4    4    5    4    3
```

Comment: Hello! This worked for me once I converted my df to a matrix. I am having issues now with NA in my data, as this code converts NA to one of the possible unique identifiers. Do you know how I might account for that?

edit: figured it out- just switch them to NA after, as the numbers assigned don't matter too much. 

Thank you!

Comment: Or you could insert a line `refs <- refs[!is.na(refs)]` to keep the `NA`s as they are.

Answer (score 2):

You could reshape it to long format, assign the groups and then recast it to wide:

```
library(data.table)

df_m <- melt(df, id.vars = "IID")
setDT(df_m)[, id := .GRP, by = .(gsub("(.*).","\\1", df_m$variable), value)]
dcast(df_m, IID ~ variable, value.var = "id")

#  IID L1.1 L1.2 L2.1 L2.2
#1   1    1    1    6    9
#2   2    2    4    7   10
#3   3    3    2    8    6
#4   4    1    5    9    8
```

This should also be easily expandable to multiple groups of columns. I.e. if you have  `L3.` it should work with that as well.