# R unique ID renumbering for each group in a data.frame

Tags: r, dataframe, unique

I want to create a unique sequential numeric ID for each distinct group based on 3 columns, but for each group the IDs must start from 1 to n.

Using the solution at [Creating a unique ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13566562/creating-a-unique-id-in-r), I can create unique IDs, but they are sequential for the entire data frame.

```
k1 <- c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1)
k2 <- c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2)
k3 <- rep(letters[1:2],5)

df <- as.data.frame(cbind(k1,k2, k3))

d <- transform(df, id = as.numeric(interaction(k1,k2,k3, drop=TRUE)))

d <- d[with(d, order(k1,k2,k3)),]
```

the result is

```
> d
   k1 k2 k3 id
1   1  1  a  1
3   1  1  a  1
5   1  1  a  1
2   1  1  b  3
4   1  1  b  3
7   1  2  a  2
9   1  2  a  2
6   1  2  b  4
8   1  2  b  4
10  1  2  b  4
```

and I'd like to have

```
> d
   k1 k2 k3 id
1   1  1  a  1
3   1  1  a  1
5   1  1  a  1
2   1  1  b  2
4   1  1  b  2
7   1  2  a  1
9   1  2  a  1
6   1  2  b  2
8   1  2  b  2
10  1  2  b  2
```

Answer (score 3):

Try using `data.table` as mentioned in the link:

```
library(data.table)

setDT(df)[,id:=.GRP,by=list(k1,k3)][]

#    k1 k2 k3 id
# 1:  1  1  a  1
# 2:  1  1  b  2
# 3:  1  1  a  1
# 4:  1  1  b  2
# 5:  1  1  a  1
# 6:  1  2  b  2
# 7:  1  2  a  1
# 8:  1  2  b  2
# 9:  1  2  a  1
#10:  1  2  b  2
```

Comment: but this way k2 its not being used to evaluate the id, if I insert it gives me back the first solution.

Comment: by the result you propose, k2 has no influence on determining the id ;)

Comment: In this special case even k1 can be omitted.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
 d$id <- with(d, ave(id, k2, FUN=function(x) as.numeric(factor(x))))
 d$id 
 #[1] 1 1 1 2 2 1 1 2 2 2
```

Comment: it works :) Great. but it depends on the previous ID right?  how to have the ID in just one pass?

Comment: @jcarlos I just used the previous 'id' you created. you can directly use it on the `interaction(..)` group

Comment: @jcarlos I think the option by data.table (ColonelBeauvel) would be more direct as it has the `.GRP`