# To convert categorical column to numerical column ¿define function?¿load package?

Tags: r

I'm using this procedure to convert categorical values to numeric values using levels and merge from reshape2 library. (just two columns shown for the sake of brevity)

data

```
    printerM  user

    RICOH     Pam
    CANON     Clara
    TOSHIBA   Joe
    RICOH     Fred
    CANON     Clark

printers.df <- data.frame(printers=unique(data$printerM))
numbers.df <- data.frame(numbers=1:length(unique(data$printerM))
printers.table <- as.data.frame(cbind(printers.df, numbers.df))
library(reshape2)
new.data<- merge(data, printers.table)
new.data$printers <- NULL
```

new.data

```
    printer  user   numbers

    RICOH     Pam      1
    CANON     Clara    2
    TOSHIBA   Joe      3
    RICOH     Fred     1      
    CANON     Clark    2
```

The issue is I got 34 columns and I'm not very happy of writing the same code 34 times, so I suppose this can be handled by:

1.- converting my code into a function
2.- using an existing R function

Not very versed on converting my R code into a function, and I don't know if this kind of transformation is available in any library.

Anyway, any hint will be much appreciated.

Comment: Are you just trying to create group ids per `printer`? Something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13566562/creating-a-unique-id-in-r) maybe?

Comment: Nor really grouping @David , just translating to numbers a categorical value. And avoiding to do it 34 times

Comment: Did you see the question I linked?

Comment: Yes, my bad. I thought that a two dimensions interaction was needed. Tested with just one column and worked ok. Shorter to write this 34 times than my code. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are applying this function to columns of a data frame you could make use of the fact that it is really a list underneath. For each column or list component, you want to convert to numeric if it is a factor and retain other columns as they were if I understand correctly. I will give a dummy example which does this:

```
df = data.frame(sample(letters[1:5],10,replace=TRUE),
                runif(10),
                sample(LETTERS[1:5],10,replace=TRUE),
                sample(letters[11:15],10,replace=TRUE))
colnames(df) = paste0("X",1:4)
data.frame(lapply(df, function(x) if(is.factor(x)) as.numeric(x) else x))
```

**Edit:**

Note this will change all columns that are factors as it is checking each column as to whether or not it is a factor, if it is then return that factor cast to a numeric, otherwise return the original column. It is possible to also keep the original factor with the new numeric encoding too, you could have `list(x,as.numeric(x))` in place of the `as.numeric(x)` but by default column names will become a bit funny.