# Sequencing along a list, reading files from folder and applying a given function

Tags: r, tidyverse

I need help to modify my code to do the following tasks... I've used help from the following questions and answers thus far

- [Opening all files in a folder, and applying a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9564489/opening-all-files-in-a-folder-and-applying-a-function)
- [How to assign a unique ID number to each group of identical values    in a column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13566562/add-id-column-by-group)

Here are things i hope to be able to do with my code...

1. I need to read in several files from a folder
2. I will like to use the name of each of the files in the folder to add a column. I was able to do this simply with 'mutate' but for a single file
3. I will like to save the result of each file separately and also combine to a single file
4. I also want to keep the code for reading the files separate from the function, so i can apply to other projects.
5. I'm trying to avoid using the *'loop'* statements

Here is the sample of my incomplete code which gives error

```
library(tidyverse)
library(readr)
cleaningdata<- function(data){
  data$Label<-gsub(".tif", "", data$Label)
  data %>% select(Label:Solidity) %>%group_by(Label)%>%
    mutate(view = seq_along(Label), Station="T1-1")%>%
    rename(Species = Label)%>%
    mutate(view = recode(view, "1" = "a","2" = "b","3" = "c"))
}

filenames <- list.files("Data", pattern="*.txt", full.names=TRUE)
ldf <- lapply(filenames, read.txt)
res <- lapply(ldf, cleaningdata)
```

Here is a sample of my dataset [Data Folder](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/pp2e9m6gug97p0f/AAAsIkV-xK1GW6g50CoYaUifa?dl=0) and below is my work thus far

Comment: `read.txt` is not a valid `tidyverse`, `readr` or `base` function. Did you mean to use `readr::read_tsv`? The file format dictates which function you should use to read your data, not the file extension. If so, your code currently does not throw an error so you will need to elaborate

Comment: @ruaridhw, Please look at the things i want to do listed, they part you commented on is just to read in the file and doesn't really change the problem.

Comment: From what you've provided, that *is* the problem. You've specified that the sample throws an error and I've indicated why and how to fix it. I would suggest including your error in the question or fleshing out the sample a bit more as each of these points have been answered already on SO.

Comment: @ruaridhw, this is the error "Warning message:
Unreplaced values treated as NA as .x is not compatible. Please specify replacements exhaustively or supply .default"... My problem is that i still don't fully understand how the lapply work. And as i said, i just need help to modify my code to be able to do the four listed tasks because if my code was working, i won't be asking for help.

Comment: @ruaridhw...By the way, i replace 'read.txt' with 'read.delim2' still not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `fs` package contains the useful `dir_map` function, which applies a function to each file in the path. If you need more control over the files to use, you could alternatively pipe a vector of the filenames into `purrr::map()` instead.

Your error `Warning message: Unreplaced values treated as NA as .x is not compatible. Please specify replacements exhaustively or supply .default` was because you were recoding `1, 2, 3` to `a, b, c` but one of the `Species` had 6 rows so `4, 5, 6` were recoded to `NA`. I've used `letters[n]` to avoid this problem.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(fs)

result <- dir_map(path = 'Data', fun = function(filepath) {
  read_tsv(filepath) %>%
    select(-1) %>%
    rename(Species = Label) %>%
    mutate(Species = sub('.tif$', '', Species)) %>%
    group_by(Species) %>%
    mutate(
      View = seq_along(Species),
      View = letters[View], # a, b, c, etc. instead of 1, 2, 3, etc.
      Station = sub('.txt$', '', basename(filepath))
    )
})

# get rows from second file
result[[2]]

# bind rows from all files
result %>% bind_rows()
```

Comment: Wow Thanks, it works exactly the way I was expecting... You made my day !!!